# Keep shared resource like json files available for tests with full paths

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm working on some file parsers/readers/writers/converters with the pretty simple api `MyReadedFileType myFile = ReaderService.Read(fullFilePath)`. Inside that method there is something like `File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath)`

I am looking for a best way to store some of those test files to be available for tests. Right now I am just including those files with `CopyToOutput` flag for "Resources" folder and then getting Path in tests using `$"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Resources`

But I found another problem when I have my tests in multiple modules `Readers.Tests`, `Writer.Tests`, `Converters.Tests` etc. I have duplicated files all over the place. What would be best approach to create single main Resources "repo" that will be accessible by all the tests and I could access each and every file with `path`?

Is there easy way to create another module `TestsData` add a flag `CopyToOutput` to it's `Resources` and then access it in some easy way like `$"{TestsData.SomeDomain.BaseDirectory}Resources"`

Comment: You could add another level of abstraction and add a FileSystemReader and an EmbeddedResourceFileReader.

Answer (score 2):

One option that I can think of is to embed the test data files in a library and access them through a utility method.

For Example: Consider that the test data files are organized as below in the project structure

```
Data/
  JSON/
     Scenario001.json
     Scenario002.json
     Scenario003.json
  XML/
     Scenario001.xml
```

Set the build action on each of the files to `Embedded Resource`

Now, introduce a class for assisting in accessing the contents of the embedded files

```
public class TestData
{
    public static Stream Read(string path)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return null;

        path = path.Replace('/', '.');

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path);

        return stream;
    }
}
```

Add this project as a dependency to the test projects and access the file contents as below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var contents = TestData.Read("Data/JSON/Scenario003.json");

        // use the contents

        // Assert
    }
}
```